# If Python Packaging is implicit since 3.3, why does my interpreter not treat all subdirectories as packages?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.3, python-packaging

I am barely understanding Python packages.

If packaging is implicit since 3.3, why does this directory structure:

```
outer_dir/
    outside_main.py
    package_example/
        module_main.py
        tests/
            test_1.py
            …
        level_1/
            foo_1.py
            level_2/
                foo_2.py
```

With these files:

```py
# module_main.py

from level_1.foo_1 import foo_function_1
from level_1.level_2.foo_2 import foo_function_2


def main():
    print(foo_1())
    print(foo_2())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```py
# outside_main.py

from package_example.module_main import main

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Give me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/outside_main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from module_example.module_main import main
  File "/path/to/module_example/module_main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from level_1.foo_1 import foo_function_1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'level_1'
```

Shouldn't `tests/` and `level_1` be implicitly treated as sub-packages of `package_example/`?

Would the situation resolve itself if I littered the directories with indiscriminate `__init__.py` files?

Comment: Because explicit is better than implicit. PEP 20.

Comment: @jwal can you expand on why explicit is better than implicit?

Comment: Because [PEP 20](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) says so. Also see `import this`.

Comment: One [interpretation](https://eng.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Computer_Science/Programming_Languages/Book%3A_Making_Games_with_Python_and_Pygame_(Sweigart)/06%3A_Simulate/6.21%3A_Explicit_is_Better_Than_Implicit): "To make your code more readable, it is better to have your code be explicit (that is, clearly state something even if it might be obvious) rather than implicit (that is, leaving it up to the person reading code to know how it works without outright telling them)." Here's [another](https://miguelgfierro.com/blog/2018/python-pro-tips-understanding-explicit-is-better-than-implicit/).